# Does equal amount of constructor and destructor calls ensure no memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

Let's say we have a class called `memoryCounter` that tries to catch memory leaks caused by `MyClass` class.

```
class memoryCounter
{
public:
    static int MyClassCount;
};
int memoryCounter::MyClassCount = 0;
```

Let's also say we put the following lines in the constructor and destructor of `MyClass` (and any other constructors that it has, assuming also that we don't modify the `MyClassCount` anywhere else outside the constructors/destructors):

```
MyClass()
{
    memoryCounter::MyClassCount++;
}
virtual ~MyClass()
{
    memoryCounter::MyClassCount--;
}
```

Now, can we be *absolutely sure* that if `memoryCounter::MyClassCount` contains zero, then all the memory we allocated this far was freed and there are no leaks? Or can there be a situation when the variable will contain zero, but there will be allocated memory that we did not free (please consider the situations where 'MyClass' is a base or derived class, too)?

Comment: If you hope to make this work even for derived classes make that destructor virtual.

Comment: There is no need for a virtual destructor. If someone is worried about deleting through a pointer to `memoryCounter`, you can inherit privately (or protected) and expose the count publicly. (Not that the OP has even suggested that `memoryCounter` should be used via inheritance -- this is not the usual CRTP counter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the count is zero, then there are no instances of `MyClass`. It applies regardless of whether the `MyClass` object is a complete object, or a base class sub-object, or for that matter a member sub-object. That doesn't necessarily mean there are no memory leaks, since maybe `MyClass` itself leaks memory.

Something to watch out for is the default-generated copy constructor. You say to assume that "any other constructors that it has" increment your global count, but it's easy to miss the constructor that doesn't appear in the code. You could have applied the rule of three here - you define a destructor so you should have defined a copy constructor. Mind you, the rule also tells you define a copy assignment operator, which in this case is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. There can be other constructors as well (copy-constructor at least). You don't count them.

Also you can't count the destruction of `static` variables so easy, because they are destructed after `main` exits

Comment: I assume that we accurately increase the variable in all the constructors, and decrease it in all the destructors. Sorry, I should have put that in the question =(

Comment: MyClass destructor will also need to be virtual.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: what about static instances ?

Answer (score 1):

Who says that only constructors allocate memory? If some non-constructor member function (static or not) allocates memory, and the destructor does not clean up properly, you have leaked that memory.

So, the answer is **no**. You have counted class instances created through the standard constructor. No more, no less.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that MyClass (and anything derived from it) are correctly written. In particular, this leak won't be detected:

```
class BadClass : private MyClass
{
  public:
     BadClass() { int *x = new int(5); }
}
```

What your counter does is tell you that you've had one destruction for each construction, which means nobody has leaked any 'MyClass' objects.

But that's not the same as no memory leaks.